# Cannot link to new Activity from Linkify pattern

Tags: java, android, linkify

I'm trying to get a certain text pattern to open an Intent. The text pattern linkifies correctly. Clicking on the text `@username` in a list view should open the Activity specified below. Instead, it opens a dialog that says `"Open with... No apps can perform this action."` and the Activity does not change. What is up here?

**Linkify Code:**

```
// Linkify @mentions
Linkify.TransformFilter filter = (match, url) -> match.group();
Pattern mentionPattern = Pattern.compile("@([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)");
String mentionScheme = "com.test.android.activity.UserProfileActivity://";
Linkify.addLinks(feedItemView.messageText, mentionPattern, mentionScheme, null, filter);
```

**Manifest:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.UserProfileActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:parentActivityName=".activity.UserProfileActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="com.test.android.activity.UserProfileActivity" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I used this as a guide: http://cogitas.net/blog/2011/01/05/linkify-your-android-textview/

Answer (score 1):

It may be too late to answer this but for other people this is how I resolve it.
Implement this to your **textView**.

```
String json_string = "{"mention_id":"1","mention_username":"mj"}";
  Pattern username_pattern = Pattern.compile("mj");
  Linkify.addLinks(yourTextView,username_pattern, "input.your.scheme://"+ json_string));
yourTextView.setLinkTextColor(Color.BLUE); // add a color to your mentioned
```

and to your **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
 <activity android:name="The activity that you want to open"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"> // add your theme here
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="input.your.scheme" />// for getting the scheme of your intent from linkify
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and to get the data from intent to your activity. Add this on your **onCreate** in the activity that you want to open.

```
//you can now parse your data here
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    if (data!=null){
        if (data.toString().contains("input.your.scheme://")){
            String[] strip_id = data.toString().split("//");
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject_mention = new JSONObject(strip_id[1]);
                getSpecificUserProfile(jsonObject_mention.optString("mention_id"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```